# Javascript refer to index like enum, refactor

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I have a const *object* that I refer to.
I refer to both the key and the value.
For reasons beyond me, I don't want to directly use the key (since it is an integer).

```
export const listObject = {
    1: "a",
    2: "b",
    3: "c",
    4: "d",
}
```

so when I map this, I refer to the key index as the *mappedIndex*, and the value as `listObject[mappedIndex]`
I want to refer to the *key* in a different way.
Would something like this work?

```
export const listObject = {
    1: "a",
    "reason1": 1,
    2: "b",
    "reason2": 2,
    3: "c",
    "reason3": 3,
    4: "d",
    "reason4": 4,
}
```

Ignore the naming convention, this was just written as an example.
so now I can refer to the *key* as `listObject[listObject.reason1]` and the value still as `listObject[mappedIndex]`
i might have all this mixed up, as of doing it this way I won't be able to map properly. any recommendations?

Comment: what is the use case for it? why not use the numbers, which are strings, as all keys of an object, beside symbols.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely wish to be able to access the object like this, I would take the following approach: First, we have our base object from you:

```
export const listObject = {
    1: "a",
    2: "b",
    ...
}
```

Then, I would create a different object that contains the keys.

```
export const listObjectKeys = {
    reason1: 1,
    reason2: 2,
    ...
}
```

Now, you could access a property in `listObject` object using `listObject[listObjectKeys.reason1]`.  I find this to be the best way to structure everything in order to not accidentally taint your `listObject` with extra rows that are actually just keys. Let me know if you have any questions or if I'm misunderstanding anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like typescript's [`enums`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html). They trasnpile to something like this in javascript:

```
const listObject = {}
listObject[listObject["reason1"] = 1] = "a";
listObject[listObject["reason2"] = 2] = "b";
listObject[listObject["reason3"] = 3] = "c";
listObject[listObject["reason4"] = 4] = "d";
```

(This is same as the second example in the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can delcare constant listObject as array of object as mentioned below:

```
 const listObject = [{"index":1,"value":"a"},{"index":2,"value":"b"}];
```

And you can access index 1 value as bleow:

listObject[0].value => "a"